# Seemingly Unrelated Regression with the same dependent variables

Tags: regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I am analyzing the effect of foreign aid on governance. Foreign aid consists of six categories and I want to know each effect. Governance is measured by one indicator.

I made six regression equations that have different independent variables (amount of aid in each category), the same control variables, and the same dependent variable.

Since all equations are theoretically related (since they all come from foreign aid), I thought it would be reasonable to use Seemingly Unrelated Regression (SUR).

However, my textbook says SUR is used when you have different independent variables.

Is it possible to use SUR in my situation

Added:
Independent variables have two parts: ones that I want to know the effect, and the ones for control.
The former part is different from equation to equation, but the latter part is same throughout the equations.

Comment: Are the rows of the X's all the same from IV to IV?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added to the original sentence.

Comment: What is the reason for which you don't specify a single equation, where all six different foreign -aid variables will appear as regressors?

Comment: Since foreign aid is provided by the US, I thought all equations are somehow related. (I tried OLS for each, but results are not so much different. The difference occurred in fourth decimal place)

Comment: From your descriptions, it doesn't sound like you need SUR;SUR may be overly complex. Why not run a single regression model as @Alecos suggests? Maybe there are more details you can provide to help understand why you think you need separate equations?